# Why does the store of a Redux application have to be serializable

Tags: serialization, redux

First of all: This is not an question of opinion (I'm afraid someone will flag this question), I'm interested in the technological background or the decisions for this.

That being said: Redux's store needs to be serializable. It is not allowed or frowned upon to use model classes and write their instances in the store. This is highly annoying to me. The applications logic ends up in actions or reducers where models would be a nice thing to have.

I am wondering why. What is the technological decision behind this? Why not write class instances to the store?

Comment: Can you give an example of a use case you are thinking of? This is something I struggled with when learning Redux but been able to avoid properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Class in instances are mutable, which leads to the same problems redux has tried to address around predictability of state by championing immutability. It also means you have to do more manual `shouldComponentUpdate` checks for changes if pairing with React (as references to mutated instances will be the same even if their internal state has changed)

2) Immutability makes it possible to move back and forth between states (eg during time travel debugging), something that cannot be done when mutations have occurred within instances

3) Serialisation means its very easy to persist and rehydrate the store (to/from JSON) for more advanced uses such as server side rendering and offline use

If you are interested I just wrote a more in depth answer to a similar question with an example of how it is possible to use the best of both worlds https://stackoverflow.com/a/47472724/7385246